# Too many re-renders with useSelector hook closure

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Considering this state, I need to select some data from it:

```
const initialState: PlacesStateT = {
    activeTicket: null,
    routes: {
        departure: {
            carriageType: 'idle',
            extras: {
                wifi_price: 0,
                linens_price: 0,
            },
        },
        arrival: {
            carriageType: 'idle',
            extras: {
                wifi_price: 0,
                linens_price: 0,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

so, I came up with two approaches:

first:

```
const useCoaches = (dir: string) => {
    const name = mapDirToRoot(dir);
    const carType = useAppSelector((state) => state.places.routes[name].carriageType);

    const infoT = useAppSelector((state) => {
        return state.places.activeTicket.trainsInfo.find((info) => {
            return info.routeName === name;
        });
    });

    const coaches = infoT.trainInfo.seatsTrainInfo.filter((coach) => {
        return coach.coach.class_type === carType;
    });

    return coaches;
};
```

and second:

```
const handlerActiveCoaches = (name: string) => (state: RootState) => {
    const { carriageType } = state.places.routes[name];
    const { activeTicket } = state.places;

    const trainInfo = activeTicket.trainsInfo.find((info) => {
        return info.routeName === name;
    });

    return trainInfo.trainInfo.seatsTrainInfo.filter((coach) => {
        return coach.coach.class_type === carriageType;
    });
};

const useActiveInfo = (dir: string) => {
    const routeName = mapDirToRoot(dir);
    const selectActiveCoaches = handlerActiveCoaches(routeName);
    const coaches = useAppSelector(selectActiveCoaches);

    return coaches;
};
```

Eventually, if the first one works ok then the second one gives a lot of useless re-renders in component. I suspect that there are problems with selectActiveCoaches closure, maybe react considers that this selector is different on every re-render but I am wrong maybe. Could you explain how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectActiveCoaches` finishes with `return seatsTrainInfo.filter()`.  This *always* returns a new array reference, and `useSelector` will force your component to re-render whenever your selector returns a different reference than last time.  So, you are forcing your component to re-render after *every* dispatched action:

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates

One option here would be to rewrite this as a memoized selector with Reselect:

https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors